# Difference between current and voltage expressions in fully differential circuits

Tags: circuit-analysis, differential, common-mode

This is an old, unimportant question. I am adding a bounty on it to effectively raise the bounty of the question linked below. Please answer the linked question for the bounty. Both bounties will be awarded (effective bounty 200).

[Two port feedback analysis of shunt-shunt amplifier with unity feedback](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/702555/two-port-feedback-analysis-of-shunt-shunt-amplifier-with-unity-feedback)

---

In the fully differential circuit below, the common-mode (CM) and differential-mode (DM) voltages are defined as
$$V_{DM} = V_1 - V_2$$
$$V_{CM} = \frac{V_1 + V_2}{2}.$$

Considering the CM and DM impedances,
$$Z_{DM} = 2Z_1$$
$$Z_{CM} = \frac{Z_1}{2} + Z_2,$$
we find that to follow Ohms law,
$$I_{DM} = \frac{V_{DM}}{Z_{DM}}$$
$$I_{CM} = \frac{V_{CM}}{Z_{CM}},$$
the CM and DM currents are
$$I_{DM} = \frac{I_1 - I_2}{2}$$
$$I_{CM} = I_1 + I_2.$$

Comparing the expressions for voltage and current, we see that the factor of \$\frac{1}{2}\$ is present in the DM current but missing in the DM voltage and present in the CM voltage but missing in the CM current.

Is there anything to be learned from this, for example, some underlying concept, or is it just the way it is?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZtyHd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, you'll notice that the differential circuit equation does not depend on the common mode voltage.
$$I_{DM} = \frac{V_{DM}}{Z_{DM}}$$

This is important if you want to send signals in an environment that has common mode voltages. Think RS485 and an industrial installation that might have several volts between tranciever/receiver if you were to send a single ended signal with say 5V, a 5V difference would saturate the digital line.

Another application is LVDS signalling where you want to send a very fast signal and you need more SNR, you can double the SNR by chosing VDM1 and VDM2 to be opposite from one another.

Comment: I was asking about the factor of 1/2 in the current and voltage expressions. I thought of this question when I realized (i1 - i2) is not the correct expression for differential current. Anyway, you can have the bounty—my original intention did not work out